# ControlToValidate property in CustomValidator is blank?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have the following code defined in my ASP.NET file:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator6"
            ControlToValidate="Weight1" OnServerValidate="TotalWeight" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must equal 100%"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Yet when I try stepping through my code to debug, I get a Javascript error saying "ControlToValidate propery of '' cannot be blank." This is driving me nuts - I know it's this particular control causing the problem, because if I comment it out, the page runs fine.

Has anyone seen this before and know of a fix? I've tried dropping a new custom validator on the page, setting the properties manually and through the properties window, and a little of both but I still get this error.

Comment: How are you adding the control? Are you doing anything special, like adding it dynamically?

Comment: Nope - I'm just declaring it in the .aspx file.

Comment: It might be an error in the TotalWeight function. If you use Google Chrome or Firefox you could use their debugging tools to follow the stack trace for the ajax call (that calls your server function 'TotalWeight' through javascript). That might point you in the right direction.